# What does this black and white middle-part variation of the communist flag stand for?

Tags: russian-federation, communism, flag

[image]

That was shown at a Zyuganov [rally](https://youtu.be/cIFHx4zDy1k?t=302) in 1996, but it's not clear to me if it's some kind of counter-protest that's seen in the background or if it is really the flag of communist organization I don't know about. So what does that flag stand for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like the (provocational) [NBP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Bolshevik_Party) (National Bolshevik) flag

[image: NBP flag]

This is Russian politician and writer Eduard Limonov's party, not KPRF, but keep in mind that there is more than one communist-themed movement in Russia.

Comment: It might be worth noting that while it is in part communist-themed, it is also fascism-themed (red flag + white circle; Reichsadler, etc) and has been described as neo-fascist.

Comment: Yeah black, white red were the colors of the Imperial war banner of Germany and they were prominently featured by the Nazis. And this is near identical to the Nazi party flag https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_the_NSDAP_(1920%E2%80%931945).svg only difference being the logo being swapped.

Comment: It is also Yegor Letov's party. How many communist parties were founded by a punk rocker?